# want to show selectboxes in new line with a textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var arr = [{
  val: 1,
text: 'Option 1'
   }, {
     val: 2,
   text: 'Option 2'
      }];

   $(function () {
       $('a').click(function () {
    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
    $(arr).each(function () {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    });
    return false;
  });
      });

       </script>

  <a href="">Add Select Box</a>
```

according to the above code...when i click on the above anchor tag...selectboxes appear...if i click on anchor tag 10 times then 10 selectboxes appear but on the same line ...i want that whenever i click on anchor tag a selectbox opens in new line with a textbox with it....any help would be appreciated.....thanks in advance

css fro the code...

```
      a {display: block; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #aaa; color: #000; text-decoration: none; width: 200px; padding: 5px; font-family: arial; text-align: center;}

      </style>
```

Comment: I think you need to add some CSS.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/FbUeD/1/

Comment: oh yes i wanted exactly this...thanxx a lot

Comment: helo sir can you please help me with a problem??

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
       $('a').click(function () {
           var div = $('<div/>');
           var sel = $('<select>');

           $(arr).each(function () {
               sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
           });

           div.append($("<input/>"));
           div.append(sel);
           $("body").append(div);
           return false;
       });
  });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JWkLv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add css to display the select as block as well:

```
select { display: block; }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ve49/1/

EDIT: Missed that you needed a textbox as well. See Kevins answer for a good solution :) !